# Add "active" navigation class to navbar in Django's class-based views

Tags: django

In a Django app, a lot of class-based views are called directly from the urls.py like so

```
url(r'^manage/thing/$',
    ListView.as_view(model=Thing,
                     queryset=Thing.objects.filter(parent=None)),
    name='mg_thing_list'),
```

and most CBVs are not subclassed, so views.py is almost empty. I want to highlight the active section in the navbar based on the URL. For example, pages at `/manage/thing/...` should have `class="active"` next to the "thing" item in the navbar HTML. What's the DRYest way of doing this?

I want to avoid subclassing the CBVs just to add the request to the template context (which the standard templatetag solution seems to require). Currently we do it in a dumb way: add a `{% block %}` for every navbar item tag and set the relevant block to `class="active"` in each and every template. Seems a waste.

Comment: By the way, you can add [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) to avoid your subclass headache. Is that what you need?

Comment: This is it! Thank you. (I am accepting @Mikeec3 's answer that has context processors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's not recommended to hold logic in urls.py, also there are 2 ways to go about your issue here

First a template context processor: (in myapp/context_processors.py)

```
def mytag(request):
     context = {'class': 'active'}
     return context
```

Then

```
<div class='{{ class }}'>
```

Finally add the template context processor to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py or in Django 1.8

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['components/templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'myapp.context_processors.mytag',
        ],
    },
},
```

Also, just as a very common opinion on views, you should keep view logic
in views, that way if you needed to build some mixins you could. Keep urls small.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet to add `active` class to your html code. It does a reverse resolve based on the url `name` parameter.

In `your_app/templatetags/base_utils.py`

```
from django import template
from django.core import urlresolvers

register = template.Library()    

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def current(context, url_name, return_value=' active', **kwargs):
    matches = current_url_equals(context, url_name, **kwargs)
    return return_value if matches else ''


def current_url_equals(context, url_name, **kwargs):
    resolved = False
    try:
        resolved = urlresolvers.resolve(context.get('request').path)
    except:
        pass
    matches = resolved and resolved.url_name == url_name
    if matches and kwargs:
        for key in kwargs:
            kwarg = kwargs.get(key)
            resolved_kwarg = resolved.kwargs.get(key)

            if kwarg:
                # for the comparison of same type url arg d+ w+
                kwarg = unicode(kwarg)

            if not resolved_kwarg or kwarg != resolved_kwarg:
                return False
    return matches
```

In `your_template.html`

```
{% load base_utils %}
<li class="{% current 'your_url_name' param1=param1 param_N=param_N %}"><a href="{% url 'your_url_name' param1=param1 param_N=param_N %}"> This is NavBar Button </a></li>
```

Comment: Where will the `context.get('request').path` come from? As far as I see, there's no request key in the context passed by the CBVs to the templates (Django 1.7).

Comment: The context comes from the tag registration : `@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)`

Comment: Yes there is context, but no request in it.

Comment: These are tags, I actually like his answer better than mine.

Comment: Very nice, althogh there is a problem if you use namespaced URLs like `myapp:index` - `resolved.url`_name is 'index' in this case so the comparison fails. Solution: replace `resolved.url_name == url_name` with `":".join( (resolved.namespace, resolved.url_name,) ) == url_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the question if I understand you correctly, and I solved it by using `jQuery` like this:

```
function mainNavListAddClass() {
    var theA = $("a[href=" + "'" + getCurrentUrlPath() + "'" + "]");
    if (theA.length) {
        theA.first().addClass("active");
    }
}

function getCurrentUrlPath() {
    return location.pathname;
}
```